# Multisites in joomla: Content update from another admin panel?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, multisite

I have basic question regarding Joomla multisite.

I have two website which is in joomla.

For example : 
demo1.demo.com
demo2.demo.com

And if i am usig multisite feature. Is it possible to update content of demo2.demo.com from admin panel of demo2.demo.com

Answer (score 2):

Find the joomla extenions Below link helpful https://extensions.joomla.org/category/core-enhancements/multiple-sites

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible depending on how you implement multisites.

For example, [Virtual Domains](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/virtual-domains) can be configured to work this way.